# MS Teams Dialog Bot Event Not Fired when message is sent from outside the Teams Bot

Tags: event-handling, bots, microsoft-teams, botframework

I am sending a message on an existing conversation to my MS Teams Chatbot from outside i.e. a Windows Forms Application.

```
ChannelAccount userAccount = originalActivity.From; 
ChannelAccount botAccount = new ChannelAccount("GenerateReport", "AzureFunction");

var message = new Activity();//Microsoft.Bot.Schema.Activity.CreateEventActivity();
message.Type = ActivityTypes.Message;
message.From = originalActivity.Recipient; //new ChannelAccount("GenerateReport", "AzureFunction");//botAccount;
message.Value = originalActivity; 
((Activity)message).Text = "LongOperationResponse";
message.Recipient = originalActivity.From;// userAccount;
message.ChannelId = originalActivity.ChannelId;
message.Conversation = originalActivity.Conversation;

ResourceResponse response21= await connectorClient.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)message);
```

The message activity is sent successfully and the message appears in the chat bot conversation.

I would also like to somehow trap the event when the above message is received by the ma teams chatbot.
I have attached the following Event handlers in DialogBot class that inherits from ActivityHandler class.

- OnMessageActivityAsync
- OnEventActivityAsync
- OnTurnAsync

However, none of the above event handlers get triggered when the message is sent from outside the bot using the above logic.

These event handlers get triggered only when a user types a message in the chatbot.

Which event should get triggered when an outside message is received by the team's chatbot and how do I handle the event.

Please help.

Thanks
Gagan

Comment: Outside of the teams bot mean? How you are sending the message to the bot conversation? Could you please explain your scenario in more detail?

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT I am using the following documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-long-operations-guidance?view=azure-bot-service-4.0 . Here, a long running task is sent to Azure Function which sends and Activity message to the Bot on completion of the task.

Comment: So you are sending message using code. The message was sent using bot code. The events will trigger only when message is sent by user not by bot. This is by design.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Yes, Need help.

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT Yes, I am sending message but not using bot code, but code in an external application. The Message.From is set as the Bot  and Message.Recipient is My Teams AadObjectID i.e My Teams account. I tried to reverse the From and Recipient but same results i.e. Message appaears in Teams chatbot window but no events are trigeered in bot code.

Answer (score 1):

The question was a bit unclear, but reading the comments now I think I understand it better. You are sending messages *as* the bot, but from outside *of* the bot (basically pro-active messaging). As a result, your bot code won't get notified at all because from Bot Framework's perspective, why would it tell *you* that *you* are sending a message - you'd know that already, of course. In practice, you will only get notified:

1. when a message is sent **to** your bot
2. that is further defined depending on conversation type. For a 1-1, you will get ALL messages TO your bot. For a group chat or Teams channel conversation, you will *only* get messages where you bot is @mentioned